# ViewStack not showing change at first 

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have as good as finished a new project I’m working on now for a while, and I have this small problem coming up at the fine tuning.

The area of concern is so I believe the ViewStack I’m using, but I’m not sure so here the details.

I have several check boxes (4), and only one at all times can be selected to show off associated Radio Buttons as a Group of (6). No RBtn pre selected.

With the selection of a check box I also make visible a new Radio Button Group of (4). No RBtn pre selected here either.

Now if I select one of the RBtn (6 - each has a different Paper size measurement showing) then I can view through a external Xml data file details as Size, basePrice and the totalPrice which is in this case the same as the basePrice!

This totalPrice is located on the first Canvas/Label in the VStack!

Selecting any of the first three (3) of the second RBtn Group (4) No RBtn pre selected either! – it will show me a Paper type description, and by selecting the fourth RBtn it will show me as well a field with the extra costs for a Canvas type, and it should select the second Canvas of the VStack with the totalPrice which is basePrice plus the extrasCost Canvas Price.

Now the problem is that my second VStack Canvas/Label = totalPrice (basePrice +extraCost) is not showing up immediately! (It just shows blank canceling the basePrice out), and only if I select another of the six (6) RBtn! then it is showing the second vStack with the totalPrice (basePrice +extraCost). From here on everything works perfectly! So it is just the first instance which has the problem!

I think that I have to mention that my RBtn Group are working in a function – If / Else / If /Else configuration where both the Labels on both VStack Canvases are called up at the same time. So therefore both Labels should have data available which than should be viewed when the VStack changes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the end very simple! 
I just forgot to use in this module of the App to include the (creationPolicy="all") for the ViewStack.
regards aktell